# import error when using Slick in Play

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am using play-scala-starter-example as the base for my application. I want to use 'slick' for accessing mysql DB. After following https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlick I added following lines in application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/playexamplemysql?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
slick.dbs.default.db.username="user"
slick.dbs.default.db.password="password"
```

The import is used in DbController.scala as follows:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.db._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
```

When i run this app, i get following error:

```
[error] /play-scala-starter-example/app/controllers/DbController.scala:11: object jdbc is not a member of package play.api.db.slick
[error] import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
[error]              ^
[error] /play-scala-starter-example/app/controllers/DbController.scala:12: object driver is not a member of package play.api.db.slick
[error] import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
```

Looking at slick APIs these are valid package path names.

**build.sbt:**

```
name := """play-scala"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies += jdbc
libraryDependencies += cache
libraryDependencies += ws
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "2.0.0" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36"
```

Comment: could you attach also your build.sbt?

Comment: Added build.sbt.

Comment: From my experience such problems happen when there are some incompatible versions of some libs. So hard to point a culprit in this particular case but try to play with version numbers for play-slick and mysql-connector-java. Probably also scalaVersion, try to see if it will work with 2.11.8.

Comment: Sure, I will try that. Meanwhile I switched to 'anorm' in my controller code. Will look into 'slick' later.